# Why does using an expression on an address act weird when using printf

Tags: c, printf, pointer-arithmetic, format-specifiers

```
typedef struct nodes {
    int da;
    struct nodes *ptr;
} node;

node init;

printf("%d %d %d\n", &init, &init-2 ,6295648-2);
```

prints

```
6295648 6295616 6295646
```

How come subtracting 2 from an address subtracts 32 (so subtracting 1 from an address subtracts 16)?

Comment: First of all, what is `init`? Second of all, to print a pointer you should be using the `"%p"` format to print `void *` (casting is necessary).

Comment: Is `init` a `long double`?  Or some structure type?  Most other built-in types are not 16 bytes long.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to print an address, you should be using `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `(void *)`, as required by `printf()`. Otherwise, using wrong type of argument for a supplied format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, regarding the pointer arithmetic, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
>   result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression. [...]

That means, pointer arithmetic honors the *data type* of the pointer. The result of the addition (or subtraction) of an integer with a pointer is not *just another number*, it is an address of another (possible) element , provided the exist.

> In other words, if the expression `P` points to
>   the `i`-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and
>   `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist. [...]

Answer (score 3):

When you do arithmetic on pointers, the addition or subtraction on the address is done in units of the data type that the pointer points to. This is what allows the equivalence:

```
&arr[n] = arr + n;
```

So if `sizeof init = 8`, then `&init - 2` will subtract 16 bytes from the address.

Answer (score 2):

When you do *pointer arithmetic* you the basic unit is the base-type. For example, if you do pointer arithmetic on a pointer to `int`, i.e. `int*`, then you do it in units of `sizeof(int)`.

Let me illustrate it: Lets say we have

```
int *pi = malloc(...);  // Actual size doesn't matter for this example
```

In memory it's something like

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| pi[0] | pi[1] | pi[2] | ..... |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
^       ^       ^       ^
|       |       |       |
pi+0    pi+1    pi+2    pi+3
```

The above illustration should hopefully also explain a little between the relationship between pointers and arrays, especially why the expression `pi[x]` is the same as `*(pi + x)`. Those expressions are the same both for pointers *and* arrays.

Now by *subtracting* from a pointer, you will have a pointer to *before* what the pointer points to. Just printing the pointer is okay, but in most cases you can't dereference it (get the value where it points).

Answer (score 1):

Because 16 is the size of whatever `init` points to.

The following three are equivalent:

- `ptr[offset]`
- `*(ptr + offset)`
- `offset[ptr]` (but don't do that)

So when you add or subtract something from `init`, the calculated address is dependent on the size of the type pointed to by `init`. If the size is 16, every offset calculated will be a multiple of 16.

Comment: `8` is the size of whatever `init` points to (because OP is subtracting 2, not 1)

Comment: Not my DV, but I guess the problem is that the question doesn't use subscripting and you don't directly explain how what you write applies to the question.

Comment: @TomKnapen I believe he say 16 when subtracting 1 and 32 when subtracting 2 in the question.

Comment: @TomKnapen: The numbers end 48 and 16; the difference is 32 for subtracting 2, so subtracting 1 gives a difference of 16 (not 8).

Comment: I should stop checking SO at 9am, pardon me

Answer (score 1):

In C, subtracting 2 to an `int` or a pointer isn't the same. It's [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm).
With an `int` pointer, subtracting 2 will move the pointer position by `2*sizeof(int)`.
If you cast your pointer to `int` before decrementing it, you will retrieve the same.